# global variables can be defined inside comments?

Tags: javascript, jake

So I'm doing a tutorial (a chapter on linting) and I get these errors

```
jakefile.js failed
4: task("default", ["lint"]);
   'task' is not defined.
7: task("lint", [],function(){
   'task' is not defined.
6: desc("Lint everything");
   'desc' is not defined.
9: var files = new jake.FileList();
   'jake' is not defined.
```

and the 'fix' is to put the following at the top of jakefile.js

```
/*global desc, task, jake, fail, complete */
```

whereas

What is this bizarreness?

The jake [docs](http://jakejs.com/docs) I found don't make any mention that this is a special jake syntax.

But it sure isn't regular JavaScript... Is it special lint syntax?

Comment: The `/*global desc, task, jake, fail, complete */` comment doesn't actually do anything, it's only for some JavaScript linters.

Comment: It''s using a lint tool that looks for certain specific comments. Has nothing to do with the language.

Comment: okay, so once I look into lint a bit more, it will make sense... thanks